# Finding Min and max in a range in a column Vba

Tags: excel, vba, max, min

I have been trying to find the min and max of a column and Cannot seem to get my code to work correctly. I have tried if statements, for loops and cannot seem to make it work. I have also been using application.worksheetfunction.min/max and have not been able to get anything to work.

```
Sub MinMax()
    Dim xmax As Double
    Dim xmin As Double
    Dim TableRow As Integer

    For i = 2 To lastrow   
        If cells("i,11").Value < cells(i + 1, 11).Value Then
            xmin = cells(i, 11).Value
            cells(3, 16).Value = xmin
        End If

        If cells(i, 11).Value > cells(i + 1, 11).Value Then
            cells(2, 16).Value = xmax
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Where is `lastrow` assigned? That's effectively `For i = 2 To 0`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub MinMax()

    Dim xmax As Double
    Dim xmin As Double

    Dim r As Range

    Set r = Range("K2:K" & Rows.Count)
    xmin = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(r)
    xmax = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(r)
End Sub
```

Comment: I also need to have that min and or max be attached to a ticker symbol from another column. Would you know where to start with that?

Comment: Don't mean to be rude, but google.com ;) Probably you need a Function, not a Sub. And use this function to attache - but it's only guessing.

Comment: If you feel that my answer helped you, you could [accept my answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235).